# How to get on item click listener the name of the layout clicked inside the item of a list view?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a list view, for which I implemented a custom adapter. Each item(row) of the list view is composed of several linear layouts. So when I implement the OnItemClickListener, I can't find a solution to get the name or the id of the linear layout clicked.
Can I find any help to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

In `tag` field in XML you can give name and can access in the code part